# Why is Tuesday sometimes Sunday?

Tags: sql, oracle, date

`select to_char(sysdate, 'DAY') from dual;` will return `TUESDAY` correctly.

But why is it that when I run `select to_char(to_date(sysdate, 'DD-MON-YYYY'), 'DAY') from dual;` on the same day, it returns `SUNDAY`?

Thanks to a `ORA-01835: day of week conflicts with Julian date` error when I try to run `select to_date('27-OCT-15', 'D') from dual;`, I have to end up converting the date (that I pass into a function dynamically) into the `DD-MON-YYYY` format before attempting to get the day of the week from it. Does anyone know why I am seeing this inconsistency?

A better example is here (I have replaced column and table names in example).

```
SELECT  DATE, 
    to_char(DATE, 'DAY'), 
    to_char(to_date(DATE, 'DD-MON-YYYY'), 'DAY') 
FROM    DATES
ORDER BY DATE;
```

The result is;

```
DATE      TO_CHAR(D TO_CHAR(T
--------- --------- ---------
19-OCT-15 MONDAY    SATURDAY
19-OCT-15 MONDAY    SATURDAY
19-OCT-15 MONDAY    SATURDAY
21-OCT-15 WEDNESDAY MONDAY
21-OCT-15 WEDNESDAY MONDAY
02-NOV-15 MONDAY    SATURDAY
02-NOV-15 MONDAY    SATURDAY
```

Comment: I get `ORA-01843: not a valid month`, not `SUNDAY`. What's your server's default date format?

Comment: Because `to_date` return the first day of week - `SUNDAY`

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario Not 100% sure if this is what you are looking for, but my `NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE` is `AMERICAN`.

Comment: `to_date(sysdate`? Really? sysdate is a date, you dont need to cast date to date.

Comment: @NguyễnHảiTriều That doesn't seem right. When I run `to_char(to_date(SYSDATE, 'DD-MON-YYYY'), 'DAY')`, the result isn't **always** Sunday - only when the day is actually Tuesday. Mondays come out as Saturday, Sundays as Friday etc.

Comment: @Stawros I'm using SYSDATE as an example. In reality I am passing actual dates to a function.

Comment: Post some data which you are passing ..

Comment: Also check your date format using the query :
select * from nls_session_parameters where parameter = 'NLS_DATE_FORMAT';

Comment: @Dr R Dizzle Sysdate or date, doesn't matter. TO_DATE converts **char of CHAR, VARCHAR2, NCHAR, or NVARCHAR2** datatype to a value of DATE datatype. If you put date datatype, then you should be ready to any problem with implicit type conversion and nls settings.

Comment: @anwaar_hell Example added to question. My `NLS_DATE FORMAT` is `DD-MON-RR`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> to_date(sysdate

Never apply **TO_DATE** on a **DATE**. It forces Oracle to:

- first convert it into a string
- then convert it back to date

based on the **locale-specific NLS settings**. You need **TO_DATE** to convert a literal into date. For **date-arithmetic**, leave the date as it is.

```
SQL> SELECT to_char(to_date('27-OCT-2015', 'DD-MON-YYYY'), 'DAY') FROM dual;

TO_CHAR(T
---------
TUESDAY
```

**ROOT CAUSE**

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format='DD-MON-RR';

Session altered.

SQL> select to_char(to_date(sysdate,'DD-MON-YYYY'),'DD-MON-YYYY') from dual;

TO_CHAR(TO_
-----------
27-OCT-0015
```

So the year is changed to `0015`. Because, you converted **RR** format to **YYYY** for a value which is already a **DATE**.

Now, the **27th day** of **October 0015** was a **SUNDAY**.

```
SQL> select to_char(to_date('27-OCT-0015','DD-MON-YYYY'),'DAY') FROM DUAL;

TO_CHAR(T
---------
SUNDAY
```

To understand the internal behaviour, let's see a small demo:

```
SQL> SET AUTOT ON EXPLAIN
SQL> SELECT * FROM dual WHERE SYSDATE = TO_DATE(SYSDATE);

no rows selected


Execution Plan
----------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 3752461848

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation          | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT   |      |     1 |     2 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  FILTER            |      |       |       |            |          |
|   2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL| DUAL |     1 |     2 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - filter(SYSDATE@!=TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE@!)))
```

Do you see the `filter(SYSDATE@!=TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE@!)))`. What happened with the filter?

**TO_DATE** on **SYSDATE** is internally interpreted as `TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE@!))`.

So, first **TO_CHAR** is applied, which will have a format depending on your local **NLS_DATE_FORMAT**, and then converted back to **DATE**.

---

**UPDATE** Based on OP's comments below...

Use:

- **TO_DATE** to convert a date literal(string) into a **DATE**. Since, **TO_DATE** is NLS dependent, I would prefer to mention the format and **NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE** explicitly at individual statement level.

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format='YYYY-MM-DD';

Session altered.

SQL> SELECT TO_DATE('27-OCT-2015', 'DD-MON-YYYY','NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH')
  2  FROM DUAL;

TO_DATE('2
----------
2015-10-27
```

If you depend on the **client's NLS settings**, it might not work for a person who uses a different NLS in some **different location**.

```
SQL> alter session set NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE='FRENCH';

Session altered.

SQL> SELECT TO_DATE('27-OCT-2015', 'DD-MON-YYYY') from dual;
SELECT TO_DATE('27-OCT-2015', 'DD-MON-YYYY') from dual
               *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01843: not a valid month
```

- **TO_CHAR** to convert a DATE into a string to **display** in your **desired format** using a proper **FORMAT MODEL**.

Don't do it vice-versa.

Comment: In that case, why is it that when I run either `select to_char('27-OCT-2015', 'DAY') FROM DUAL;` or `select to_char('27-OCT-2015', 'DAY') FROM DUAL;` I get `ORA-01722: invalid number`? Without the `to_date`, it won't work (for me).

Comment: Why would you use **TO_CHAR** to convert a string back to string? You are doing everything fundamentally incorrect. You must use **TO_DATE** to convert it to date.

Comment: Because that's the only way I can get it to come back without an error message - using TO_DATE gives me either `day of week conflicts with Julian date` or `not a valid day of the week`.

Comment: You mean `SELECT TO_DATE('27-OCT-2015', 'DD-MON-YYYY','NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH') FROM DUAL;` doesn't work for you? I don't believe you, just copy paste this query and post the output.

Comment: It does - but I'm trying to get the day of the week from a string in the DD-MON-YY format. Which is why I tried converting to date and then converting to string 'DAY'.

Comment: so you would need to do: `SELECT to_char(TO_DATE('27-OCT-2015', 'DD-MON-YYYY','NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH'), 'DAY') FROM DUAL;`. Ie. explicitly convert your date-as-a-string into DATE datatype, and then convert it back to a string in the format you desire (in this case, DAY).

Comment: Do you have a **DATE** with you or a **STRING**?

Comment: He cannot understand that VARCHAR2 and DATE is different datatypes.

Comment: @LalitKumarB A date. The function that these appear in accepts a variable called `passed_date`, which is declared as `passed_date IN date` when the function is created.

Comment: @DrRDizzle So, you are getting a date, just use `SELECT TO_CHAR(passed_date, 'DAY') into some_variable FROM DUAL;` Else if it not a date but a string, then use the query Boneist gave above.

Answer (score 5):

Since `sysdate` is already a date this expression:

```
to_date(sysdate, 'DD-MON-YYYY')
```

... is both redundant and fragile. You ask Oracle to cast a date to string using whatever value `NLS_DATE_FORMAT`, `NLS_TERRITORY` and `NLS_LANGUAGE` currently have and then parse it as date using a fixed (and potentially different) format. Garbage in, garbage out.

A couple of tips:

1. Don't stringify dates without a good reason.
2. When casting back and forth, always specify the format.

I'm also not very fond of using month names as exchange format; I think numbers are less error prone.

Answer (score 2):

When your `nls_date format` is `DD-MON-RR`, the conversion:

```
to_date(sysdate,'dd-mon-yyyy')
```

will result in the string `27-10-0015` (where sysdate is `2015-10-27`).

In the year 15 the 27th of october was a sunday - in the then non existent Gregorian calendar.